# variables go into db without being retrieved through $_POST

Tags: php, database, post

This works but How are the values of the variables being put into the db without retrieving them through the $_POST?
Is this something new in php5 or have I just never seen it used this way before?

```
  <!doctype html>

 <html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head

<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br>
    Username:  <input type="text" name="uname" /><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

 $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
 // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO traders (fname, lname, username)
VALUES
('$fname','$lname','$uname')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} 
echo "1 record added " ;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because you use here `register globals` option in php which is now deprecated/removed in new versions of php (mainly because of security issues) which translates `$_POST['fName']` into `$fName`

you should always use `$_POST`/`$_GET` instead

read more: http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: Not only that, but never concatenate data into an SQL query!  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks, and just plain broken software.

Comment: @Brad prepared/parameterized in mysqli or PDO?

Comment: I agree with @Brad. If you're already using mysqli, take the small extra step and use parametrized queries. They're available for both mysqli and PDO

Comment: Even better, you should always use the [filter extension](http://php.net/filter). The `filter_input()` function, specifically. Always sanitizing input is a good idea, even in situations where you think it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is called Register Global and is DEPRECATED long time ago, one should never use this !

> When on, register_globals will inject your scripts with all sorts of variables, like request variables from HTML forms. This coupled with the fact that PHP doesn't require variable initialization means writing insecure code is that much easier.

For more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: thanks man I'm way behind on PHP. trying to find whats being used now. Been in C++/ASP land for the past 2 years